# jQuery Load image on select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I'm trying to load different images into a DIV according on the  selected, something like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="mercedes">Car #1</option>
  <option value="ferrari">Car #2</option>
  <option value="fiat">Car #3</option>
</select>
```

If the Car #1 es option is selected, load mercedes.jpg into `<div id="car"></div>`

Any ideas??

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler, like this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $("#car").html($("<img />", { src: $(this).val() + ".jpg" }));
});
```

When the value changes, this creates a new `<img>`, sets its source to `NEWVALUE.jpg` and uses [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set `#car`'s content to that element [`.html(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is [a shortcut for `.empty().append(element)`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L256).

Comment: Nick thanks for the quick help, but it doesn't seem to work :-|

Comment: @Alberto - Are you running this on `document.ready`? e.g. inside a `$(function() { });`...if so are these elements being added dynamically?

Comment: Nick, do you know how to do if i would like to have a pre selected item and the image loading for this element?

Comment: @Alberto - That last like, change `});` to `}).change();` to trigger it on-load, then it'll load the currently selected image, is that what you're after?  For example you could have an `<option value="pickOne">Please Select</option>` with a `pickOne.jpg`.

Comment: Your a Genius Nick!! Thanks so much, the only thing that doesn't work is navigating trough the list with the arrow keys, but that's not really necesary. I really need to learn more Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @Alberto - Unfortunately there's no event fired until a `change` is made (selected), if you use a replacement for your `<select>` (there are a few jQuery plugins out there to do this), they'll *probably* have events, or you can add one easily enough.